# How do you round a variable to the nearest number in an array in swift?

Tags: swift

I have a block of code in swift in which the final calculation needs to be rounded to the nearest number in a pre-defined array? How would you do that?

```
var array = [8, 23, 31, 46, 54, 69, 77, 92, 100, 115, 123, 138]
var finalCalculation = 55.5
//round 55.5 to the nearest number in array which is 54
```

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You are not trying to round anything. You are trying to find the number in the array that is closest to your `finalCalculation` number.

Comment: [Edit] your question showing what you have tried. We are not here do your homework for you.

Comment: I constructed a complete answer for you, but @rmaddy is correct - you need to show us what you have tried, and what didn't work.

Comment: Is the array always sorted? How large can the array be? Is performance an issue? What if two numbers are equally close? – Binary search would be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could think up was to loop through and keep track of which one was closest and compare that to the next item in the array, however, I'm sure this could be improved upon, here:

```
var array: Array<Double> = [8, 23, 31, 46, 54, 69, 77, 92, 100, 115, 123, 138]
var finalCalculation: Double = 55.5

var closest: Double = array[0]

for item in array {
    if abs(finalCalculation - item) < abs(finalCalculation - closest) {
        closest = item
    }
}

print(closest)
```

The ***abs*** part is to ensure that you're getting the distance between the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = array.reduce(100, { x, y in
    abs(Double(x) - finalCalculation) > abs(Double(y) - finalCalculation) ? y : x
})
```

The '100' is an arbitrarily large number, to start the reduce calculations. You can use whatever you like, as long as it's greater than the differential between finalCalculation and your answer.

Comment: You can choose any array element (e.g. the first) as initial value in reduce. – The same can be expressed using `min(by: ...)`.

Comment: You're correct about the first element, though I don't see the value in doing so; again, the first number is arbitrary. min(by:) is a good point. I hadn't used reduce() since the Swift 3 update, and used this as an excuse to catch up. :P

Comment: The advantage of starting with an array element is that you don't have to *guess* a sufficiently large initial value.

Comment: True. I was thinking within the context of the question, but should have abstracted to other use cases.